# How can i remove the empty spaces from a web page that i scrape?

Tags: python, regex, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a site with python3 using beautiful Soup.
I store my data into a list.

I manage to extract the info that i want

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('my site').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

lista = []

rows = soup.find('table', class_='exchange-rates-table not- 
responsive').find_all('tr')

for row in rows:          # Print all occurrences
    l.ista.append(row.contents[3].get_text())
print(lista)



This is the output:

['Cod', '\n\n                        EUR\n\n                    ', 
'\n\n                        USD\n\n                    ', '\n\n                        
GBP\n\n                    ', '\n\n                        CHF\n\n                    
', '\n\n                        AUD\n\n                    ', '\n\n                        
DKK\n\n                    ', '\n\n                        HUF\n\n                    
', '\n\n                        JPY\n\n                    ', '\n\n                        
NOK\n\n                    ', '\n\n                        SEK\n\n                    
']
```

When i run this code i am receiving the info that i want, but with a lot of empty spaces with comma between them and the sign of new line.
So how can i remove them to get only what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is already in a list, you can do with [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[x.strip() for x in ['Cod', '\n\n EUR\n\n ', '\n\n USD\n\n ', '\n\n GBP\n\n ', '\n\n CHF\n\n ', '\n\n AUD\n\n ', '\n\n DKK\n\n ', '\n\n HUF\n\n ', '\n\n JPY\n\n ', '\n\n NOK\n\n ', '\n\n SEK\n\n ']]
```

Comment: strip is the keyword, but look at the answer that i need:
    'lista = []
    for row in rows:     
        lista.append(row.contents[i].text.strip())'